# Plural of driver's license

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I just read another question where someone mentioned "driver's license" is more used than "driving license" in the US.

How do I pluralize "driver's license"?

> **Driver's licenses**

or

> **Drivers' licenses**

Same question, but suppose there are lots of girls and I want to talk about their heads. Should it be **girl's heads** or **girls' heads**?

Comment: In British English, we avoid this issue entirely by calling it a "driving license". :-)

Comment: Not every State uses the "driver's license" name. For example, New York terms theirs a "driver license", so you can do it that way too.

Comment: Same with (UK) "fishing licence". Not sure what that makes a "dog licence" ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually, the plural form of **a driver's license** should be [**driver's licenses**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver%27s_licenses_in_the_United_States) because **driver's** is fixed in form here and is used as an adjective rather than a possessive. This is very common for products and utility items. For instance: *McDonald's burgers*, *Wendy's salads*, *electrician's scissors*, *programmer's text editors*, *a voters' strike*, *children's beds*, *kids' TV* et cetera. All these examples represent the same phenomenon where the apostrophe-s construction no longer indicates possession, but acts as a descriptive word the way a regular adjective does. So, if I say:

> Do you know how to tie **the angler's loop**?

Well, it's quite obvious that this does not refer to a loop that's owned by a particular angler that only you and I know about, but rather it's describing the category of loops the loop under discussion belongs to.

It's a totally different story when we're dealing with the real possessive case. We're going to say **a girl's head** if we're talking about only one girl and **girls' heads** if we're talking about more than one girl. Of course, it's also possible to say **a girl's heads**, but in this case we're assuming that the girl has not one but several heads! Maybe, she literally has several heads (scary!) or she's just holding a bunch of doll heads in her hand or something to that effect. So, there's nothing surprising here, just standard English grammar.

Comment: If someone is pointing some drivers (persons) and say "these drivers' licenses". If someone is pointing at some licenses (things) on table and say "these driver's licenses". It depends on the context what we are talking about. Am I right or not? I'm not sure about it, just a doubt.

Comment: That's exactly right. But this issue arises only in writing because in real speech all of these different variations would sound exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah, but there is only one **McDonald** and one **Wendy**.  Each driver's license is of a different person unless one person has a bunch of these licenses.

Comment: You may be right, though. This is a tough one as we are talking about a compound noun. I've upvoted you for that reason.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know possessive like **driver's**  can be used as an adjective, learned a lot!

Comment: Yes, it even confused me for a second because I seldom see this written in the plural, Ives. I agree with them, though, after having discussed it with them as it is a fixed form since "driver's license" is a compound noun (open form).

Answer (score 3):

I agree above that it would be **driver's licenses** because it is fixed in form.  It would also be **girls' heads** because you are talking about multiple girls in this instance.  Chances are that one girl doesn't have multiple heads.

This is only for writing these two possibilities out as both are pronounced the same way, i.e., **driver's**, **drivers'**, and **drivers** are all pronounced the same way and so are **girl's**, **girls'**, and **girls**.  This only matters for purposes of spelling.

I hope that might have helped you out, Ives.  Take care and good luck.

Comment: Thank you, Does **Their drivers' licenses** look natural?

Comment: Yes, it would be fine. In fact, many native speakers just write **drivers** rather than **driver's** or **drivers'** in these situations because it is a compound noun rather than a possessive adjective--that is, one could not replace **drivers'** with the possessive adjective **their** to form "**Their their** licenses". Do you comprehend what I'm trying to say here?

Comment: "These **drivers'** licenses" would be correct if talking about "their licenses", but it should be "he has many **driver's** licenses" if talking about the compound noun.