# Driving license or Driver's license?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I got my driving license or I got my driver's license.

Which is correct?

This [article](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/driver-license-vs-drivers-license/) says Driver's license is correct, while it seems to me someone is saying that he has the license of his/her driver.

To me, a driving license makes more sense, it means that I got my license to drive. I am not a native and my major is not English, I hope someone can guide me. Thanks.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/is-it-a-driver-license-or-a-drivers-license-or-a-drivers-license-or-wha

Comment: And [this thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151541/plural-of-drivers-license) also has great points.

Comment: It is called what the issuing authority calls it. My UK licence says DRIVING LICENCE.

Comment: Doesn't the article basically answer your question?  [The New York State DMV calls it a "driver license"](https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-licenses) but like Weather Vane says, it's really up to what the issuing authority calls it.

Comment: well the question is how to use it in daily life, I mean more than what anyone says it. like I am in China, so if I have to use this term here. what should I say? both are correct?

Comment: I think the confusion here is that these licenses tend to be treated as proper nouns that, like @WeatherVane says, is just determined by the issuer. I have only ever heard "Driver's License" so that is what I have always consider as correct. But, for example, a "dragon license" could mean that you are allowed to BE a dragon, or OWN a dragon, or RAISE dragons, or SALE dragons, or many other possible purposes of the license, but the NAME of the license does not attempt to describe it's purpose, instead it is just a name.

Comment: I'm upvoting this question since there's no reason to downvote it. The OP linked an article to his question to help others understand his post and asked for clarification about a legitimate doubt that he had.

Comment: The term varies from country to country, so if you don't know the standard usage among English speakers where you are, you can use either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possessive "driver's" is correct.

It isn't "[my driver's] license", the license that belongs to my driver; rather it's "my [driver's license]", the license that the state gives to any driver, and this one is mine.

You'll see this a lot with licenses. A trucker's license, a pilot's license, and so on. The license belongs to a driver, a trucker, a pilot. And since I have one, that makes me legally a driver, a trucker, or a pilot.

That said, "driving license" is also correct and completely normal to say.  You can also have a hunting license, a scuba diving license, or a teaching license.

Both are correct and acceptable in normal usage.

Answer (score 1):

As a British person, I've heard both. If I had to choose, I probably have a preference for driver's license. The word driver is being used very generally; it's not referring anyone in particular; it's just a license that drivers have. And in the phrase "my driver's license," I naturally recognise "driver's license" as a single object so "my driver's license" is the license that **I** have. I think that just comes from hearing the phrase a lot.

If I actually tried to say "my driver's license" meaning *the license belonging to my driver*, I think it would take some gesturing or extra stress on the words "my driver" to somehow communicate that I'm talking about someone else because it's unusual. It's not what the person I'm talking to would expect. The easiest thing to say in that situation might be "the license of my driver"/"the license that my driver has" instead.